# how to restore subdataset window (Do Not Ask Again) checked by mistake

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, hdf

I checked "Do Not Ask Again" check box by mistake.Choosing this option automatically loads the first subdataset for any HDF without opening the subdataset selection. so how to fix this problem? I need to choose one of the subdataset in a modis image.

i m using arcmap 10.3

Comment: What software are you using?  You have a tag for ArcGIS Desktop but unless it is stated in the body of your question it is possible that you have just chosen a popular tag.

Comment: i m using arcmap 10.3

Comment: delete the normal.mxt http://help.arcgis.com/EN/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00v000000005000000

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a checkbox available to do this from the Main Menu of ArcMap (I checked ArcGIS 10.3.1) under Customize | ArcMap Options and the Raster tab:

[image]